# Instantly type in the text box, without having to click it WPF

Tags: wpf

I have tried Keyboard.Focus() in the initialize component. Doesnt work.

Im clicking on button to open a new window for an input from the user. I want the user to be able to instantly start typing without having to click on the text box first and then type.

Is there any simple way to get this donw

Comment: KeyBoard.Focus() won't work there, use textBox.Focus() in initialize , it will work. KeyBoard.Focus() can work if you do after controls has been loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it in `Loaded` event of the window. And, as far as I know, simply using `MyTextBox.focus()` should give it both logical focus and keyboard focus.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple.

```
<Window FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=SomeElement}">

   <TextBox x:Name="SomeElement"/>
     ...

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managing Focus is hard! Without going in to the details, it is about getting things done in the right order, have I in the past been successfull with a brute force approach:

In the `Loaded` event of the window:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() =>
        {
          myTextBox.Focus();
          Keyboard.Focus(myTextBox);
          FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(myWindow, myTextBox);
        });
```